# PhoneGap File API issue while saving image captured on a directory

Tags: android, image, cordova, fileapi

I have following code to store the image in a directory "myApp" on S4

```
function gotFileEntry(fileEntry){   
var gotFileSystem = function(fileSystem) {
    alert("got file Sys: " + fileSystem.name);

    fileSystem.root.getDirectory("myApp", {
        create : true
    }, function(dataDir) {
        alert("got dir :" + dataDir.fullPath);
        alert("got image file entry: " + fileEntry.fullPath);
        // move the file
        fileEntry.moveTo(dataDir, "1.jpg", null, failFS);

    }, failFS);

};

 window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFileSystem,failFS);
}

function SaveImage(){
   // curImageURI has value of imageURI  from onPhotoURISuccess()
   window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(curImageURI, gotFileEntry, failFS);
}
```

> Path on S4 for "myApp" directory : /storage/emulated/0/myApp
>
> Value in  curImageURI : /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.apps.myApp/cache/1392602140698.jpg
>
> Below are the alerts I got: 
>   got file Sys: persistent 
>  
>   got dir : //myApp 
>   got image file entry: /1392602140698.jpg

I get below error upon fileEntry.moveTo(...).

> System.err java.io.FileNotFoundException: The source does not exist

I don't understand where I am going wrong. I would really appreciate if anyone can help me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is you consider my answer correct, please check as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. This is a bug related to phonegap 3.3.0 en older. Please refer to the release notes:

[Phonegap (Cordova) 3.4.0 Release notes](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=12312420&version=12324813)

1. Upgrade your phonegap version.

   MAC/Linux: $ npm update -g phonegap

   Windows: C:> npm update -g phonegap
2. create the project from scratch and test your code, it should work.

   phonegap create test
3. Enter in the created directory:

   cd test
4. Build for android:

   phonegap build android
5. Copy/Paste your code and test.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I was having a pretty similar issue.

In my camera api call, i was resizing the image with `targetWidth: ,targetHeight:` 
I kept getting the source does not exist error.

I removed the width and height and it works as it should.

Comment: chris, Are u able to share your working code. and for which phonegap version have u succeed.